# Is Rails 3.1 ready for production use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

From what I saw on their Github page, the Rails development team has been releasing Release Candidate versions since May, and the most recent tag is v3.1.0.rc6.

I found many comments on Google about new features, but almost no critiques or experience tails.

So, are you using Rails 3.1 already? If so, in production environments? And also, what has been your experience? Are there any gems that absolutely won't work with Rails 3.1?

I appreciate any comments/opinions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is git issues for Rails 3.1: [Rails 3.1 issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues?milestone=1&sort=created&direction=desc&state=open)

you can check that it near to final realease :). As for me I use Rails 3.1 in my work. And we have some projects already in production mode. As for gems, so I havent met gems that do not completely work with Rails 3.1. But anyway you should use most fresh version of your favourite gems or use completely new ones. So have a try on Rails 3.1 - it is stable and have many awesome new features.

Comment: I checked the link, but I didn't understand how you draw your conclusion. I thought this page showed issues (problems, bugs), and not development tasks that are left. But, from what you said, Rails 3.1 is undergoing an issue correction phase, and when that's over (as of now, there are 13 issues left), Rails 3.1 will be released (if no more issues get reported), is that it?

Comment: I told you that, there are not to much issues left for final Rails 3.1 release.

Comment: If you wish you can port your projects to production. Rails 3.1 is quite stable now (I have not seen any crashes in my work). But anyway it is your decision about migration to 3.1. I just gave you my experience.